# Filtering by user input getting error message can not get table 0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I have wrote code following a tutorial posted here 
http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-filter.htm

However I keep getting the error "Cannot find table 0", I have tried several things but none have worked

i have posted the code in my form load and the button to start the process

```
string connectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=epas=";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM pricing sterling";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
con.Open();
dataadapter.Fill(ds, "pricing table");
con.Close();

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

And the button

```
DataView dv;
dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0], "ID = '21' ", "type Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: `pricing sterling` shouldn't be `[pricing sterling]`?

Comment: I changed pricing sterling to [pricing sterling], I also noticed I had named it "Pricing table" second time, but thats also fixed.

Comment: However it still is returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces from the name of the datatable in

> dataadapter.Fill(ds, "pricingtable");

Comment: Just did this and also tried changing it in the database in mySQL but still getting this error message  
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot find table 0.